# Can I remove the "New table" button from the Navigation Tree in PHPMyAdmin (4.0.9)?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Every database listed in the left-hand pane has a "New" button for creating a new table, i.e. the first item in this tree.

[image]

It takes up room and I don't need it. There doesn't seem to be a config variable for removing it. Happy to remove it by hand from the PHP but I've done a quick search and can't find it.

Comment: i highly doubt you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the PHP with grep -R.

In `libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node_Table_Container.class.php` I commented out a few lines:

[image]

and that did the trick.